# How to configure Mosquitto in Docker to have read/write access

Tags: docker, mqtt, mosquitto

I have the issue that my Mosquitto broker on my Synology cannot open or access a log file in a directory the docker container is mapped to. The structure it is aiming for exists, I even created the 'mosquitto.log' for it in the attempt to overcome the problem.

I installed Mosquitto in Docker through:

```
sudo docker run --name="mqtt" --restart=always --net=host -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 -v /volume1/docker/mqtt/config:/mosquitto/config -v /volume1/docker/mqtt/log:/mosquitto/log -v /volume1/docker/mqtt/data:/mosquitto/data -tid eclipse-mosquitto
```

The container runs, but the log shows

```
Error: Unable to open log file /mqtt/log/mosquitto.log for writing.
Error: No such file or directory.
```

Looking for a solution I found this thread -> [GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1078) but changing ownership or rights does not change a thing.

The container I created goes by the name mqtt and, within my docker directory there is a structure with the following rights:

```
docker
|_ drwxrwxrwx  1     1883  1883  26 Jan  8 14:33 mqtt
|  |_ drwxrwxrwx 1 1883 1883 28 Jan 14 16:57 config
|  |  |_ -rwxrwxrwx 1 1883 1883 280 Jan 14 17:02 mosquitto.conf
|  |_ drwxrwxrwx 1 1883 1883  0 Jan  8 14:33 data
|  |_ drwxrwxrwx 1 1883 1883 26 Jan 14 17:09 log
```

and mosquitto.conf looks like this

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mqtt/data/

log_dest stdout
log_dest file /mqtt/log/mosquitto.log
log_type warning
log_timestamp true
connection_messages true
```

and I did not create a user or a group that goes by 1883

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-v /volume1/docker/mqtt/log:/mosquitto/log`

This makes the folder available as `/mosquitto/log` in the container. But in your config you are telling mosquitto to log to `/mqtt/log/mosquitto.log` which does not match the above.

Either use `-v /volume1/docker/mqtt/log:/mqtt/log` or change the `mosquitto.conf` to use  `/mosquitto/log` (I'd suggest the second option as this matches the defaults used in the docker image; you should also update `persistence_location`).

Comment: You will also need to the fix the `persistence_location` to match the mounted volume as well.